# How to get the response as an attachment using Soap UI

Tags: rest, soapui

Ok, so I am very much new to Soap UI and trying to test a REST webservice which returns an attachment(.docm) as a response. While running the service, I am getting the response in binary stream but not the attachment.

Infact in the response section -- Header tab, I can see the attachment name in content-disposition column (See the attached image) but attachment tab is empty.

Am I missing something ? Do I need to write any groovy script for the same ? Please suggest. Appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Comment: Documentation is here: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#2-Attachments-and-Inline-Files Attachments are handled the same between SOAP and REST in SoapUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, So I got the solution. Posting it here if someone else faces this issue.

There are some settings which need be enabled for the same. 
I have added 1 more parameter in the Request details tab with the value as

```
Enable MTOM = true
```

Also, I have added the values in Dump file column under Test Request properties. See the screenshot attached.

[image]:)

Hope it helps others as well. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Adding "Enable MTOM" as Header parameter in rest request and "Dump File" as Property parameter, it's works.